# Text not wrapping in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, word-wrap

Can anyone tell me why the text inside a div in a row-direction flex container doesn't wrap properly but it goes overflow?

If I change the direction to the `section`, the text will wrap, I don't understand why...

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin: 0;
}

div,
main,
section {
  align-items: stretch;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

section {
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1280px;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: start;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <section>
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eget nulla sagittis sem egestas molestie. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: seems to work fine in the snippet, you must have some other styles messing up whatever doesn't work for you

Comment: Where exactly does the text overflow? I don't see it in your code snippet.

Comment: Sorry I changed the code

Comment: Do you have more information on how exactly you are trying to format the text?  Changing certain properties such as flex-shrink for example can have a massive change, but it all depends on what exactly you are wanting to accomplish with the text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's clarify the structure:

1. Your `main`, `section` and `div` elements are flex containers.
2. `section` is a flex item in `main`.
3. `div` is a flex item in `section`.
4. `main` is not a flex item because its parent (`body`) is not a flex container.
5. All flex items are set to `flex-shrink: 0`.

Here's the layout:

- Note: Most of the code in the question is not necessary to reproduce the problem, so I removed it.
- Note: Each flex container is highlighted.

```css
div,
main,
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

section {
  padding: 60px 0;
}

main    { background-color: lightgreen; }
section { border: 2px dashed red; }
div     { border: 1px dashed black; }
body    { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eget nulla sagittis sem egestas molestie. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Here's what's happening:

1. `flex-shrink: 0` on `div` (black border) is preventing it from shrinking.
2. `flex-shrink: 0` on `div` is expanding its parent, the `section` element (red border).
3. `flex-shrink: 0` on `section` is preventing it from shrinking.
4. `flex-shrink: 0` on `section` is *not* expanding its parent, the `main` element (green background), because `main` is not a flex item and `flex-shrink` doesn't apply.
5. `main` is standard block-level element (i.e., an element in a *block formatting context*) and [the default **`overflow: visible`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) applies.
6. If you make the `body` element a flex container, then the `main` element becomes a flex item, the specified `flex-shrink: 0` applies, and `main` expands based on its descendants, as well.

So the solution is to **enable shrinking**.

```css
div,
main,
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 1; /* adjusted */
}

section {
  padding: 60px 0;
}

main    { background-color: lightgreen; }
section { border: 2px dashed red; }
div     { border: 1px dashed black; }
body    { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eget nulla sagittis sem egestas molestie. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Plus1 for a better explanation than I have in the dupe's answer :)

Comment: Thanks! But how come instagram has all 0 shrink o.o

Comment: @xdev, you would have to post the code so it can be reviewed. There are many factors that affect the size and flexibility of flex items. `flex-shrink` was the issue in this case.

Comment: but it seems to have flex-shrink 0 on all its flex items and some of them have row direction